# How to load this into a Main class in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm learning some AS3 basics and would like to set up a native menu up the top of the window.

I found this menu example at Adobe: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7de7.html

How would I add this to my Main class so that the menu appears please?

The MenuExample class is in the same dir as Main

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import MenuClass;
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    private static var _instance:Main = null;
    public function Main() {
        _instance = this;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    }
    public static function getInstance():Main { return _instance; }
    public static function getStage():Stage { return getInstance().stage; }
    private var Menu:MenuExample = new MenuExample();

    private function init(e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        //_menu = new MenuExample(stage); //correct way to do it
    }

}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to import that class and instantiate it (meaning something like **var M:MenuExample = new MenuExample;**). You need to target AIR for Windiws/MacOS for that menu to do its things, it won't work in web player or projectors.

Comment: Hey Shaun, much of programming is trial and error. You will have to try this on your own, just start copy pasting some of the code into Main() and if you run into issues you can't figure out yourself, we can help you understand things.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm able to connect MenuExample now (have updated the above code to reflect this). A couple of questions if you are able to offer advice please? 1. MenuExample is throwing the error: "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference" re this line: stage.nativeWindow.menu = new NativeMenu(); . I tried passing "stage" in from Main but it didn't like it. 2. Because getStage() in Main is public, should I not be able to access is in MenuExample? It won't let me. I know that's not a proper OOP way of doing it, but I'm trying to get my head around inheritance

Comment: The **stage** property of any given **DisplayObject** is not **null** when this object is attached to the display list. Now looking at that example closer, I see that this **MenuExample** class is devised so it should be assigned to some Library symbol and designed to the main timeline. I think you should extend it with the **stage**-detecting routine: if **stage** is not available then wait for the ADDED_TO_STAGE event.